# Azure Cognitives services speech to text accentuation on Spanish

Tags: azure, speech-recognition, azure-cognitive-services

I'm having issues with the c++ sdk of Azure cognitives services speech to text with the spanish language related to accentuation.

I'm seeing the following error:

'sÃ' instead of 'Si' or 'Sí' which will be the correct transcription.

I'm guessing this is due to the api responde encoding. Is there any way to set headers to enable response on UTF-8 or any encoding with full spanish support?

Answer (score 0):

The return is UTF8 encoded, if you redirect the output to file and load it into a UTF8 capable editor, you will see the text is actually correct. the problem is UTF8 output in the Windows cmd console.

There are several stackoverflow discussions about this. Perhaps something like this helps: [how to convert utf-8 to ASCII in c++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2980253/how-to-convert-utf-8-to-ascii-in-c/2980768#2980768)